# Hibernate: How to model an Inheritance type structure and do operations without explicit casting

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, data-modeling, multi-table-inheritance

I have an application that consumes incoming messages, parses the data present in the message, and then applies rules to that data. On the **Rule** entity, there's a column that distinguishes the **type** of rule.

I want to persist the **Result** of the rule to **separate tables or subclasses**, depending on what **type** of **Rule** processed them.

I'm currently solving this by creating a parent `@MappedSuperclass` (abstract) **BaseResult** object and an  **AppleResult** and **OrangeResult** `@Enitiy` that extends the **BaseResult**.

My question is, given the statement below, how can I improve/annotate my objects in the model so that I don't have to do an instanceof check for each instance as I go to access/persist it? Right now this is what I'm having to do to avoid "baseresult does not exist" SQL grammar exceptions:

```
public void save(BaseResult baseResult) {
    if (baseResult instanceof AppleResult) {
        jpaApi.em().merge((AppleResult) baseResult);
    } else if (baseResult instanceof OrangeResult) {
        jpaApi.em().merge((OrangeResult) baseResult);
    }
}
```

I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution than having to do a if/else and explicitly cast depending on the result. I've looking into using things like `@DiscriminatorValue` annotation of using Generics, but these all seem to require that the `BaseResult` in my case is also an entity, which it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@Inheritance`. Then, saving would be as simple as:

```
public void save(final BaseResult baseResult) {
    jpaApi.em().merge(baseResult);
}
```

Which inheritance strategy to use depends on your current database design, but I'm guessing that you have a table for each of the subclasses, so something like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseResult {
    //...
}

@Entity
public class AppleResult extends BaseResult {
    //...
}
```

Having `@Entity` on the superclass is not a problem, as it is `abstract` anyways..

Also, using `merge` is usually something one shouldn't do, you should just manipulate your entities within a transaction and it's automatically persisted in the database upon commit of the transaction:

```
@Transactional //either this...
public void doStuff(final ResultCommand command) {
    //begin transaction <-- ...or this
    final BaseResult result = em.find(BaseResult.class, command.getResultId());
    result.apply(command);
    //end transaction
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. Worked like a charm. Curious about the snippet below that regarding using oldStateEntity.apply(newState). I am not seeing the .apply method available when I try that...?

Comment: It's just an example of a way to manipulate the state of the entity. Since I don't know what you are actually doing to the entity I went for something generic.